# IllegalFlowLogicException: A FlowLogicRef cannot be constructed for FlowLogic

Tags: java, rpc, blockchain, corda

In my Corda I am trying to call a flow using RPC but I am getting this error while making the call to initiate the flow:

> net.corda.core.flows.IllegalFlowLogicException: A FlowLogicRef cannot
>   be constructed for FlowLogic of type
>   com.example.flow.PolicyFlow$Initiator: due to missing constructor for
>   arguments: [class com.example.state.PolicyState]

My Flow is shown in the snippet below:

```
 public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
        class SignTxFlow extends SignTransactionFlow {
            private SignTxFlow(FlowSession otherPartyFlow, ProgressTracker progressTracker) {
                super(otherPartyFlow, progressTracker);
            }

            @Override
            protected void checkTransaction(SignedTransaction stx) {
                requireThat(require -> {
                    ContractState output = stx.getTx().getOutputs().get(0).getData();
                    require.using("This must be an Policy transaction.", output instanceof PolicyState);
                    PolicyState policy = (PolicyState) output;
                    require.using("I won't accept Policy without a first Name.", (!(policy.getFirstName().equals(""))));
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }

        return subFlow(new SignTxFlow(otherPartyFlow, SignTransactionFlow.Companion.tracker()));
    }
```

The Function for RPC Connection and initiating the flow is given below:
[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you show you PolicyFlow.Initiator code? specifically the class constructor.

Comment: Here is my complete code of PolicyFlow https://ideone.com/e.js/VKuAac

Answer (score 4):

Please check the constructor of `PolicyFlow$Initiator` Class there is a mismatch in constructor: you are sending `policy` but the constructor expects something else as I can see in code you provided in comments. there is no constructor in that class that accepts a policy state. You've a constructor with 10 fields.